# Add delay inside function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've found a nice Confetti script that i'm using as an effect when a winner is announced in a piece of my code.

I've got the Confetti start bound to a button called "startConfetti".

I've also got a different button "bt1" that starts the winner selection process.

Now I've got a script that clicks "startConfetti" when i click on "bt1"

```
 $('#container').on("click", '#bt1', function (e) {
        $('#startConfetti').trigger(e.type);
    });
```

Now what i want is to add a delay between the click of "startConfetti".

So here is some of the code.
This starts the confetti when you click "startConfetti"

```
function StartConfetti() {
          W = window.innerWidth;
          H = window.innerHeight;
          canvas.width = W;
          canvas.height = H;
          (function animloop() {
              if (animationComplete) return null;
              animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
              return Draw();
          })();
      }
```

And here are my buttons

```
 <div id="container">
            <button id="startConfetti" style="display: none" ></button>    
            <button id="bt1" class="button button5">< R30K</button>
            <button id="bt2" class="button button5">R30K - R70K</button>
            <button id="bt3" class="button button5">> R70K</button>
        </div>
```

and button initialize

```
function InitializeButton() {
          $('#startConfetti').click(InitializeConfetti);
          $('#stopConfetti').click(DeactivateConfetti);
          $('#restartConfetti').click(RestartConfetti);
      }
```

as well as startConfetti initialize

```
function InitializeConfetti() {
          canvas.style.display = 'block';
          particles = [];
          animationComplete = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
              var particleColor = particleColors.getColor();
              particles.push(new confettiParticle(particleColor));
          }
          StartConfetti();
      }
```

I've tried this -

```
 $('#bt1').on("click", '#startConfetti', function (e) {
 }); setTimeout(function() {
    $('#startConfetti').trigger('click');
 }, 29000);
```

But that makes the script run on its own and automatically delays the script on page load after 29 sec.

I've also tried adding

```
setTimeout(startConfetti, 29000);
```

in a couple of places in the code but still has no affect.

What am I not doing or what am I doing wrong to achieve "bt1" to click "startConfetti" button and add a delay before the "startConfetti" script runs?

Comment: You could try to put the setTimeout-code INSIDE the onclick-handler, (in your example it is outside)

Comment: Here is complete script http://jsfiddle.net/v4dfLbro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were placing the timeout outside of the event callback. So the click would to nothing and the timeout would start as soon as the code loads.

Just put the timeout inside the event callback.

```
$('#bt1').on("click", '#startConfetti', function (e) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#startConfetti').trigger('click');
     }, 29000);
 });
```

Another option would be to just wrap the startConfetti function in a timeout if you want the delay to happen whenever the function gets called.

```
function StartConfetti() {
      setTimeout(function(){
          W = window.innerWidth;
          H = window.innerHeight;
          canvas.width = W;
          canvas.height = H;
          (function animloop() {
              if (animationComplete) return null;
              animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
              return Draw();
          })();
      }, 29000);
  }
```

Comment: Testing both of your options, it seems that I've got a different problem. The moment i click either "bt1" or "startConfetti" the confetti falls immediately without any delay.

Comment: Had a look, there's something weird going on with the way you're registering and triggering the events. I'm not exactly why this happens, will require a lot of digging, but if you just remove the script tag from the html and then in your js just add 
          $('#bt1').click(InitializeConfetti)
to your InitializeButton function it works

Comment: Thanks @Shane_lL, your code help and worked perfect. Much appreciated man

Answer (score 1):

Execute the timeout inside the click event, for example:

```
 function InitializeConfetti() {
              canvas.style.display = 'block';
              particles = [];
              animationComplete = false;
              for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                  var particleColor = particleColors.getColor();
                  particles.push(new confettiParticle(particleColor));
              }
              setTimeout(function() {
                StartConfetti();
              }, 29000);


          }
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with my code because as soon as I click the "startConfetti" button or the "bt1" the confetti starts falling immediately.

Comment: your are calling your code twice in the jsfiddle one time in the console and one time from the github

Comment: Thank you @madalinivascu, after a couple of tweaks to my own code the help you provided made everything work perfectly. Thanks for your time.